# Javascript Nesting Quotes not clear

Tags: nested, quotes

What will be the Nesting Quotes for this

```
"javascript:window.open('http://localhost:9000/index.html#/mypage/detailspage\',
'details-page','width=300,height=250');"
```

I tried this not working

```
"javascript:window.open(\'http://localhost:9000/index.html#/mypage/detailspage\',
 \'details-page\',\'width=300,height=250\');"
```

Comment: `"javascript:window.open('http://localhost:9000/index.html#/mypage/detailspage\',
'details-page','width=300,height=250');"` is it not wokring?

Comment: a="javascript:window.open(\'http://localhost:9000/index.html#/m‌​ypage/detailspage\'"

Comment: a="javascript:window.open(\'http://localhost:9000/index.html#/m‌​ypage/detailspage\'" this one works fine in chrome I checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the reply but it is now working for me. Actually my requirement is that from my app I am passing the value as a  post request to another app in that app I am not able to see my code as I am sending it. Below is the example

`<input type="hidden" name="value11" id="value11" ng-model="indexedArray[34]" value="javascript:window.open('http://localhost:9000/index.html#/abc/details-page\' ,\'details-page\',\'width=300,height=250\'');" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">`

In response I am getting this

`<a href="javascript:window.open(" http: localhost:9000 index.html# abc details-page' ' target="_blank"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var y="javascript:window.open('http://localhost:9000/index.html#/mypage/detailspage\' ,\'details-page\',\'width=300,height=250\'')";
alert(y);
```

This works fine in browser i guess.